# print query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to print my query on laravel and my query is 
`DB::table('avt_channel_billing_address')->where('channel_id',$channel_id)->update($channelList)` where $channel is an array of values.

I tried using `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` and `toSql` .None print the query.

Comment: both should work. I just tried and worked for me.

Comment: @imrealashu i tried this  DB::table('avt_channel_billing_address')->where('channel_id',$channel_id)->update($channelList)->toSql(); Didnt work

Comment: I've posted a answer. Try that once. I've tried locally it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
DB::table('avt_channel_billing_address')->where('channel_id',$channel_id)->update($channelList)
dd(DB::getQueryLog())
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = User::select("*")->toSql();
dd($query);
```

Another way:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$users = User::select("*")->get();
$quries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($quries)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to turn it on: `DB::enableQueryLog();` and than call `DB::getQueryLog()`